# Django unable to find it's login templates?

Tags: python, django

A django project 'dataScan' has its template directory on the same level as the main project module and which contain files such as 'login.html', 'logout.html' etc. This configuration is identical to another project but in this case I get

```
**Request Method:   GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version:     1.6.2
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    login.html**
```

when I attempt to go to the login screen.

The *.html files were copied into the the template directories from ther other project where they  worked. The 'dataScan/urls.py' is also identical to the other project and settings.py are similar to the previous project. The only difference is that this new project uses django 1.6.2 and python 3.3 while the other was django 1.51. and python 2.7

The login is for the built in user management system.

This seems like a very trivial problem but I've been looking at it for 3 hours and can't resolve the issue so far!

Comment: Mysterious bug! Can you edit in some info showing directory structure, relevant urls.py, relevant settings.py, etc?

Answer (score 2):

is your login.html within a "registration" directory inside your templates directory?
do you have os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), 'templates'), or some other location pointer to your template folder properly set in your settings?

Comment: This nuance is really unclear in the docs (and traceback for that matter).  Was messing around with `registration/` right alongside `templates/` for way too long.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After adding

```
**TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/Users/donfox1/Projects/OpenEMR/EMRtecSolutions/dataScan/templates/'
)**
```

to settings.py the templates are now being found!

Thanks!